# Chef use cookbook_file in ruby block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have the following code to figure out where Java is located on the box. Java comes with our application and what Java version that is included with the application differs.

```
def app_java_home
  if Dir.exist?("#{app_home}/jre-server/linux")
    Dir.chdir("#{app_home}/jre-server/linux") do
      Dir.glob('jdk*').select { |f| File.directory? f }[0]
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in my cookbook I have

```
aws_s3_file "#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}" do
  bucket app_s3['bucket']
  remote_path app_s3['remote_path']
  region aws_region
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?(app_bin_dir) }
  not_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
end

execute 'extract' do
  user 'root'
  command "unzip #{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']} > /dev/null"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?("#{app_home}/ourapp") }
  only_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
end

execute 'move' do
  user 'root'
  command "mv #{app_download_path}/ourapp/ #{app_install_path}"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?(app_home) }
end

cookbook_file "#{app_java_home}/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar" do
  source %W[#{app_release}/local_policy.jar default/local_policy.jar]
  owner app_user_name
  group app_group_name
  mode 0755
end

cookbook_file "#{app_java_home}/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar" do
  source %W[#{app_release}/US_export_policy.jar default/US_export_policy.jar]
  owner app_user_name
  group app_group_name
  mode 0755
end
```

However, the two `cookbook_file` resources fails because it can't find the directory:

```
No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /ourapp/jre-server/linux/
```

After a lot of googling, I've come to the conclusion that it's a .. "missmatch" (?) between compile time and run time of the recipes. Basically, if I understand it correctly, it tries to run the `cookbook_file` resource(s) first but fails. So never downloads, unpacks and installs the app artefact.

I've tried running `app_java_home` when the directory exists, and it does seem to work the way I want it..

I tried putting the `cookbook_file` resources in a `ruby_block`, but then I instead get:

```
undefined method `cookbook_file' for Chef::Resource::RubyBlock
```

The `app_java_home` .. function (?) used to look like this:

```
def app_java_home
  "#{app_home}/jre-server/linux/#{jdk_version}"
end
```

Where `jdk_version` came from the databag. This worked fine, but we have a long standing bug/feature request in our system where it sometimes happens that "they" get the version they put in the databag wrong, causing all sorts of problems.. So they want a way to remove this dependency and instead "figure this out" dynamically.

Ruby and Chef isn't my forte, so I'm not sure what to try next. I have found references to `Chef::Resources::CookbookFile` (which, if I understand it, could/should be used inside `ruby_block`s), but can't find any examples or documentation about it. The link on RubyDocs is broken.

Comment: Is `app_java_home` part of cookbook? How do you run it?

Comment: I took that code into the Ruby shell and ran it. Both before and after creating the directory, and it works. The problem when it is in the cookbook (libraries/attributes.rb) is that it seems to be running "at the wrong time".

Comment: Can't tell from the concise error posted in question, but `@ dir_chdir` seems to indicate an issue at `Dir.chdir` in the `app_java_home` method. The `cookbook_file` resource does not need to change directory. Is `#{app_home}` created by code in recipe?

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that the `cookbook_file` is run *before* the `aws_s3_file` and the two `execute` which unpacks and installs the app. So when the `cookbook_file` runs, that directory doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Ok. So this is what will happen when you run the recipe - `app_java_home` home runs during **compile** time to get the return value. All the resources declared in the recipe will run in the **converge** phase and *in the order they are defined*. Only if there is a `cookbook_file` resource above `aws_s3_file`, it will run before it, not otherwise.

Comment: Right, thanx. That at least confirms what I'm seeing. Is there any way to get around this, rewrite part of it perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer here for a better explanation.

- Any (Ruby) code that is not within any of the Chef resources, will run in Compile phase
- All resource declarations will run in Convergence phase in the order they are defined

Thankfully, there is a way to make resources run in Compile phase if so required. Though IMHO it should be done sparingly and in exceptional cases.

As per your comment `aws_s3_file` and `execute` resources are the ones that unpack the app (and create the directory). In this case, it seems you want them to run in compile phase.

---

**Prior to Chef client 16.0**

Use the `run_action` option with the action that should be performed at the compile time. For example `execute` resource takes action `:run`:

```rb
# Note action ":nothing" and "run_action"

execute 'extract' do
  user 'root'
  command "unzip #{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']} > /dev/null"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?("#{app_home}/ourapp") }
  only_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:run)
```

---

**Chef client 16.0 onwards**

We can add a [common property](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/) to the resources. Example with `execute` resource:

```rb
# Note the extra property "compile_time"

execute 'extract' do
  user 'root'
  command "unzip #{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']} > /dev/null"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?("#{app_home}/ourapp") }
  only_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
  compile_time true
end
```

---

**And finally to answer the subject of the question:**

> Chef use cookbook_file in ruby block

This is not possible. Refer to the first point on the top. If we want Ruby code to run during converge (instead of compile), we put it within the `ruby_block` resource. So it can contain code like (for example):

```rb
ruby_block 'get directory' do
  block do
    def app_java_home
      "#{app_home}/jre-server/linux/#{jdk_version}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I put `compile_time true ` in the two `execute` and in the `aws_s3_file`, I get `undefined method `compile_time' for Custom resource aws_s3_file from cookbook aws`. But taking `compile_time` as a hint, I inverted the suggestion. Putting `compile_time false` in the two `cookbook_file` resources instead. Unfortunately, that gave the same error - `undefined method`. But unfortunately, even when doing *exactly* as you suggest, I get `undefined method for Chef::Resource::Execute`!

Comment: However, these tests indicated that I actually want ALL of it to run in the *run* phase, *not* the compile phase. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The `aws_s3_file` custom resource may not support this property, but other in-built Chef resources should. `compile_time false` is usually implied and is the default behaviour of resources. I have used `compile_time` true in `execute` resource and it doesn't give error as `undefined_method`.

Comment: When was that option added? I *thought* I was running a fairly new one - v12.13.37.

Comment: Oh! That explains it, Documentation says this support was added to *all resources* in 16.0. There is a way to run resources in compile time in a different way for previous versions. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Create a new answer for that one, for those that already use v16, that first answer could be usefull.

Comment: Done. I updated the answer for < 16.0 and > 16.0.

Comment: Ok, so unfortunately that gave me `No resource or method named 'action_run' for Custom resource aws_s3_file`.

Comment: So if you noticed, the `run_action` takes the action supported by that resource. `:run` is supported by `execute` resource. As per [aws cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws) valid actions for `aws_s3_file` are: `create`, `create_if_missing`, `delete`, `touch`. Use one of these.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @seshadri_c, I finally managed to solve the problem! It took some doing, because I kept misunderstanding the suggestions etc.

So this is what I came up with (for posterity):

```
def jdk_version(required = true)
  base_dir = "#{app_home}/jre-server/linux"
  if Dir.exist?("#{base_dir}")
    Dir.chdir("#{app_home}/jre-server/linux") do
      Dir.glob("jdk*").each do |f|
        if File.directory?(f)
          return "#{f}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

def app_java_home
  return "#{app_home}/jre-server/linux/#{jdk_version}"
end
```

Turns out I need to get just the version, individually, as well, so I rearranged the functions a bit. I'm sure it could be written much cleaner, but here the trick was to use `return` instead of `puts/print`! Well, I'm a programmer, but not a Ruby programmer so didn't know that was an option..

Then, in the cookbook, I added the `.run_action()` where needed. I didn't need them for the `cookbook_file`, which simplified things a bit:

```
aws_s3_file "#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}" do
  bucket app_s3['bucket']
  remote_path app_s3['remote_path']
  region aws_region
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?(app_bin_dir) }
  not_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
end.run_action(:create)

execute 'extract' do
  user 'root'
  command "unzip #{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']} > /dev/null"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?("#{app_home}/app") }
  only_if { ::File.exists?("#{app_download_path}/#{app_s3['archive_file']}") }
end.run_action(:run)

execute 'move' do
  user 'root'
  command "mv #{app_download_path}/app/ #{app_install_path}"
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?(app_home) }
end.run_action(:run)


#  JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files
cookbook_file "#{app_java_home}/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar" do
  source %W[#{app_release}/local_policy.jar default/local_policy.jar]
  owner app_user_name
  group app_group_name
  mode 0755
end

cookbook_file "#{app_java_home}/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar" do
  source %W[#{app_release}/US_export_policy.jar default/US_export_policy.jar]
  owner app_user_name
  group app_group_name
  mode 0755
end
```

With all that, everything is running exactly when they're supposed to and everything seems to be working.

Comment: Good to know you found the solution! Just a trivial note, `return` keyword is optional in Ruby methods, any value can be specified at the end and it will be returned by default.